# How can you replace a full span using jquery including the class, etc (not just the text)?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html:

```
 <span class=descriptionLink complete">Test</span>
```

jquery code:

```
 var name = card.find(".descriptionLink");
 name.html("<span class='newLink incomplete'>Test 1</span>");
```

But what I realized is that its creating a span within a span because html() seems to show whatever I put inside the span (not replacing it)

```
 <span class=descriptionLink complete">
          <span class='newLink incomplete'>Test 1</span>
 </span>
```

What is the best way to replace the full span (not just change the text or html inside of it?)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)** instead of `.html()`:

> Replace each element in the set of matched elements with the provided
>   new content and return the set of elements that was removed.

```
name.replaceWith("<span class='newLink incomplete'>Test 1</span>");
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) to achieve this.

> Description: Replace each element in the set of matched elements with
>   the provided new content and return the set of elements that was
>   removed.

In this case:

```
var name = card.find(".descriptionLink");
name.replaceWith("<span class='newLink incomplete'>Test 1</span>");
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8vvL3/)

Answer (score 1):

Using `.html()` replaces the contents of the selector with HTML. You want to replace the selector itself with HTML content, so use `.replaceWith` instead:

```
var name = card.find(".descriptionLink");
name.replaceWith("<span class='newLink incomplete'>Test 1</span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quote:

```
<span class="descriptionLink complete">Test</span>

//     here ^^^
```

And use replaceWith jquery method:

```
var name = card.find(".descriptionLink");
name.replaceWith("<span class='newLink incomplete'>Test 1</span>");
```